# Vuetify How to blur, focus out clicked chips?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle, vuetify.js

I have Vuetify truoble with toggling chips.

When I click a tag it gets *selected* and it's great. When I click *clear tags* all of them looses *selected* attribute that's great too.

The trouble is that when I once click a chip -> it get *selected* and when click again it **looses selected attribute in selected tags** but **looks selected until it looses focus** = until I click somewhere else. That is not UX I want users to have.

How can I achieve correct toggling? Means clicked chip gets and looses selected attribute while being clicked.

Is there a way to focusout, or blur selectedTag in my *toggleTags* method?
Point me to right direction please.

```
<v-chip v-for="categoryTag in tag.categoryTags"
        :key="categoryTag.id"
        label
        small
        outline
        color="info"
        :selected="isSelected(categoryTag)"
        @click="toggleTags(categoryTag)">
  {{categoryTag.name}}
</v-chip>

methods: {
toggleTags(clickedTag) {
  if (this.isSelected(clickedTag)) {
    this.selectedTags = this.selectedTags.filter(tag => tag !== clickedTag);
    return;
  }
  this.selectedTags.push(clickedTag);
},
clearTags() {
  this.selectedTags = [];
},
```

},

[working pen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/ZmxGJL?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom css

```
.v-chip:focus:not(.v-chip--selected):after {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Check [demo here](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/OrPGEq)